# How to correctly slice after arrange? (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not able to slice according to the code specified. See a reproducible example below:

```
library(alr4)
library(tidyverse)

modelUN <- lm(fertility ~ ppgdp, data = UN11)
```

I want to label the two highest and lowest residuals.

```
library(broom)

UN11 <- UN11 %>% mutate(Residuals = augment(modelUN) %>% pull(.resid))
UN11 %>% arrange(Residuals) %>% slice_head(n = 2)
```

This does not give me the lowest residuals. I tried saving the dataset (thinking that its fetching from the original df) but the result is the same. How should I go ahead?

Comment: Edited for clarity and correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `slice_head` or `slice_tail` returns the head and tail rows based on the `n` given.  If it is to get both ends, we can use the `slice` with the index (`1:2` - head, and `(n()-1):n()` for tail

```
library(dplyr)
UN11 %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(Residuals) %>%
    dplyr::slice(c(1:2, (n()-1):n()))
```

---

Or make use of `row_number` with `head/tail`

```
UN11 %>%
   dplyr::arrange(Residuals) %>%
   dplyr::slice(c(head(row_number(), 2), tail(row_number(), 2)))
#   region  group fertility  ppgdp lifeExpF pctUrban Residuals
#1 Europe  other     1.134 4477.7    78.40       49 -1.900575
#2 Europe  other     1.450 1625.8    73.48       48 -1.675868
#3 Africa africa     6.300 1237.8    50.04       36  3.161712
#4 Africa africa     6.925  357.7    55.77       17  3.758539
```

and using `head`

```
UN11 %>%
    arrange(Residuals)  %>% 
    head(2)
#  region group fertility  ppgdp lifeExpF pctUrban Residuals
#1 Europe other     1.134 4477.7    78.40       49 -1.900575
#2 Europe other     1.450 1625.8    73.48       48 -1.675868
```

---

Or another option is `slice_min/slice_max` and bind them together with `bind_rows` (but it is less efficient and less direct than the index option in `slice`)

```
UN11 %>% 
  slice_min(Residuals, n = 2) %>%
  bind_rows(UN11 %>% 
     slice_max(Residuals, n = 2))
```

Comment: Thats nice! My problem is that the slices are not giving me the first two rows according to the arrange function.

Comment: @AmoghJoshi Do you want it to be grouped by 'region', 'group", ?

Comment: If you run this code, the residual value if filtered by arrange for the first two rows is -1.90. However, the slice code gives me incorrect first and the last values. The first two values fetched by the code is: -0.79 and 0.48 (for the last one).

Comment: @AmoghJoshi I get the `-1.900575` and `-1.675868` as first and second rows from `arrange`

Comment: @AmoghJoshi It is possible that you loaded some other package that have `slice` function and it masked the `dplyr::slice`.  Can you change it to `dplyr::slice` as in the updated solution

Comment: Okay, this is working! I think you were right! Thanks!